# object.prototype javascript does delete new object

Tags: javascript, object, constructor, prototype

http://codepen.io/haikudoichi/pen/OPYBQN

Everything seems to be working except for the delete option. When I click on the circle object, I want to be able to delete it. However it's acting funky.

Is this correct?

```
var sqrt = Math.sqrt((this.x - x)^2 + (this.y - y)^2);
```

Comment: Can you expand on "*acting funky*"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"**^**" does not work, try this:

```
var sqrt = Math.sqrt(((this.x - x) * (this.x - x)) + ((this.y - y) * (this.y - y)));
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to do this instead:

```
var sqrt = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(this.x - x, 2) + Math.pow(this.y - y, 2));
```

`^` is the Bitwise XOR operator.

Comment: thank you, i should have caught that/knew that. accepted previous answer as it was posted a hair faster